# NoClassDefFoundError error when trying to start my spring/vaadin application

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I downloaded a get started the project from the vaadin website but when I try to run it I get this error and don't know what wrong

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:206)
at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/jav

a.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 2 more
```

It's telling me that it's not picking up the class and is happening every time I try to run the code trouigh typing mvnw un the termnal but get greeted by this error

Class

```
    package com.example.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.vaadin.artur.helpers.LaunchUtil;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.NpmPackage;


/**
 * The entry point of the Spring Boot application.
 */
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@NpmPackage(value = "lumo-css-framework", version = "^4.0.10")
@NpmPackage(value = "line-awesome", version = "1.3.0")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LaunchUtil.launchBrowserInDevelopmentMode(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args));

    }

}
```

Comment: Dumb question maybe but is `commons-logging.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: I don't know and how can i find out?

Comment: How did you build the application?

Comment: By using the build tool in intelej

Comment: Where in Vaadin website did you download the starter from? start.vaadin.com or elsewhere? Also, did you make any changes to the pom.xml of the downloaded starter?

Comment: @Dunmol try to delete the build folder / and / or try to go to "File" and then "Invalidate Caches" and then "Invalidate Caches and Restart".